# Expected Value Of a Random Variable X

Tags: probability, random-variables, random

Consider an experiment that is successful with probability $0.8$. We 
repeat this experiment (independently) until it is successful for the 
first time. The first $5$ times we do the experiment, we have to pay 
$\$10$ per experiment. After this, we have to pay $\$5$ per experiment. 
Define the random variable $X$ to be the total amount of money that we 
have to pay during all experiments. Determine the expected value 
$(X)$.

I tried solving it using linearity of expectations and geometric distribution, but I am sure I was wrong.

Any help on how to solve this?

Comment: Okay and what do you think about the problem?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören what do you mean?

Comment: your own opinions about how to solve this problem. Dont you have any idea?

Comment: no. that's way I am asking for help. as I mentioned in the question I tried using linearity of expectations and geometric distribution but I don't think it is correct

Comment: Okay so the game continues until we get the first hit. It  means we have infinitely many possible cases with all having non zero probabilities right? Every event is independent so the probability of current event and the next event dont affect each other. Then what is the probability that we stop right away? what is the probability that we stop for the second time? third time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability of the program lasting precisely $n$ experiments is 
$$ (0.2)^{n-1}\cdot (0.8) $$

Break the problem into two regions:  Find the expected number and cost of expensive experiments, and add the cost of inexpensive experiments.

The expected cost of the expensive experiments, each of which requires $n-1$ previous failures to be needed, is
$$
 10 \sum_{n=1}^5  (0.2)^{n-1} 
$$
which is just a geomentric sum with value
$$
10 \cdot  \cdot \frac{1-(0.2)^5}{1-(0.2)} = \$12.496
$$
 The expected cost of the \$5  experiments, each of which requires $n-1$ previous failures to be needed, is
$$
5 \sum_{n=6}^\infty  (0.2)^{n-1} = 5 \cdot (0.2)^5 \frac{1}{1-(0.2)} =\$0.002
$$
And the sum of these is 
$$
\$12.498
$$

Answer (score 0):

If Pr(N)  is the probability of reaching N trials before a successful outcome.

Assuming you mean the Expected cost of any single trial.

E(cost) = 10*( Pr(1) + Pr(2) + Pr(3) + Pr(4) + Pr(5)) + 5* sum(Pr(n)) N=6 to inf